# Can I groupby with conditions and return the source type value

Tags: c#, group-by

I have following scripts data:

| Database | File |
| --- | --- |
| master | sql_master |
| myDB | sql_sameGroup1 |
| myDB | sql_sameGroup2 |
| myDB | sql_sameGroup3 |
| myDB | sql_special |

`scripts.GroupBy(script => new { script.Database, script.File})`
will make it 5 groups but I only want 3 groups -
The rule is that distinguish by Database, then for same Database, **if `File != sql_special`, I want to put it into the same group** - this means in the above table Row1 is group1, Row 2,3,4 is group2, Row5 is group3. and return the scripts type for further processing.

I didn't find suitable `GroupBy` method overload. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep grouping by both the Database and File property, but instead of the whole File property, just check if it is `sql_special` or not.

```
scripts
    .GroupBy(script => new 
    { 
        script.Database, 
        IsSqlSpecial = script.File is "sql_special" 
    })
```

[Runnable online version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lvACpT)